# Chain a RxJava observable to udpate/create an entry in Room database

Tags: android, rx-java, android-room, rx-android

I want a way to search and update an existing entry in Room with RxJava. If there's no record it should create a new one.

For example, lets say I have the following queries:

```
@Insert
Single<Long> createContent(Content content);

@Query("SELECT * FROM Content WHERE contentId = :contentId")
Single<Content> searchContent(String contentId);
```

**My Goals:**

1. Check if there's a previous data and return its value
2. If there's no record create a new one and return it's value

**Problem with this approach:**

1. Whenever there's no record the from `@Query`, the `Single<Content>` directly goes to `error` ignoring any **map**/**flatMap** operator
2. The `@Insert` query returns a `Single<Long>` but the `@Query` returns a `Single<Content>`

Is there any way to call and return a new Observable from the error? Something like this:

```
daoAccess.searchContent(contentId)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .map(Resource::success)
                .onErrorResumeNext(new Function<Throwable, Single<Content>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Single<Content> apply(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                        return daoAccess.createContent(contentId);
                    }
                })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Single.onErrorResumeNext()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Single.html#onErrorResumeNext-io.reactivex.functions.Function-):

```
daoAccess.searchContent(contentId)
         .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
         .map(Resource::success)
         .onErrorResumeNext(throwable ->
             daoAccess.createContent(content)
                      .map(id -> Resource.success(content))
         )
```

Comment: I can't return a Single<Content> from onErrorResumeNext() because the first observale returns Single<Long>. Please check the updated question.

Comment: Have you noticed the `map` within the `onErrorResumeNext`? The code I posted should be consistent in regards of types. I just don't know the return type of `Resource.success()`...

Comment: My mistake, I completely missed the map operator. One last question, Please suggest me the best way to handle errors for those different observables.

Comment: This question is not clear to me. Do you mean the combined error or on the second one?

Comment: Yes, the combined error. How to catch any possible errors that might occur from any of the observable calls `searchContent()` + `createContent()`?

Comment: You would just add another `onErrorXXX` where you need it. Within the `onErrorResumeNext` function or after. Then you could even throw a `CompositeException` to not loose the errors.